# irreducibility of varieties defined by square roots equatiosn

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have the following collection of equations in matrix form:

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\pi_{ij}\pi_{ik}\pi_{jl}\pi_{kl}}+ \sqrt{\pi_{ik}\pi_{il}\pi_{jk}\pi_{jl}}+\sqrt{\pi_{il}\pi_{ij}\pi_{kl}\pi_{jk}} = 0
\end{equation}
$i,j,k,l$ are different from each other and $1\leq i,j,k,l\leq n$ Is there a software that will be able to tell me if the solutions defined by these equations are irreducible for low dimensions like $n=5,6$

Comment: What are the $\pi?$ Independent variable? So, for $n = 6,$ you are really taling about $15$ dimensions?

Comment: correct $\pi$ are independent and n=6 15 dimensions.

Comment: How many equations?

Comment: 5 for n=5 and 15 for n=6.

Comment: Is there a particular choice of signs you want to take for the square roots? For example, do you want to insist that $\sqrt{\pi_{13} \pi_{14} \pi_{23} \pi_{24}} \sqrt{\pi_{15} \pi_{16} \pi_{25} \pi_{26}} = \sqrt{\pi_{13} \pi_{15} \pi_{23} \pi_{25}} \sqrt{\pi_{14} \pi_{16} \pi_{24} \pi_{26}}$? Also, is there meant to be a relation between $\pi_{ij}$ and $\pi_{ji}$?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer from the OP's response to my question, I am guessing $\pi_{ij} = \pi_{ji}.$

Comment: @IgorRivin Me too, but I wanted to nail these points down before I wrote anything substantive. For example, with one choice of signs, one family of solutions is to take $2n$ generic variables $x_1$, \ldots, $x_n$, $y_1$, \ldots, $y_n$ and put $\pi_{ij} = (x_i y_j - x_j y_i)^{-2}$. But I don't know if that choice of signs is permissible.